# Fit entire text into a plot area

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

I want to create a plot with text but it seems that ggplot ignores text when identifying x and y limits (it uses only centerpoint). So if the text too long it is not fully visible.

```
df <- tibble(x = 1:5, y = 1:5)
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, label = paste(rep("long text", 3), collapse = " "))) +
  geom_point() + geom_text(nudge_y = 0.2)
```

[image]

In this case one can add layer `expand_limits(x = c(0.4, 5.6))` but that doesn't work for any other case. I would like to have something that works for any values of x and y and any length of text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ggrepel` for this:

```
library(ggrepel)

ggplot(df, aes(x, y, label = paste(rep("long text", 3), collapse = " "))) +
  geom_point() + ggrepel::geom_text_repel(nudge_y = 0.2, segment.alpha = 0)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks. but i need to keep the possition of the text and rather expand the limits

Comment: @JanKislinger the problem with that approach is that whether the text comes off the edge of the plot is down to your plot's width, since the width of your text string stays constant while the plot size changes. You could have a solution that works well for a given window size, but when you resize the window it will no longer work.

Comment: that actually helped me understand the problem. thanks. so the answer is that it isn't possible

Comment: @JanKislinger it's not impossible. It would just take a lot of development. The other option you may wish to explore would be `coord_cartesian(clip = "off")`